# Why isn't my cross-domain request working?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain

http://pastebin.com/B9MqcM1D

> Failed to load resource: Request header field
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

`--disable-web-security` Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header not a request header.

It has to be sent by the server you are making the request to.

CORS would be useless if the site hosting the JavaScript could *grant itself permission* to access any site on the WWW.